# Profile GPU rendering

Tags: android, profiling, rx-java, gpu, systrace

I'm trying to profile the redrawing of the TextView using **Profile GPU rendering** and **systrace** utils. There are two cases of redrawing. The first calls `setText()` when clicking on the view, the second is triggered by the rx timer `Observable.interval (1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`. In the first case Profile GPU rendering shows a slight excess of 16ms (img 1), and systrace displays an "Expensive measure / layout pass" warning. When the timer is updated, the rendering time is significantly increased (img 2), but systrace no longer displays the "Expensive measure / layout pass" warning, and the "measure / layout" stage disappears from the chart altogether, but the "Scheduling delay" warning appears. What is the difference of calling the redraw in these cases?

[image]

```
timerLabel.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        timerLabel.setText(TimeUtils.getTime(this.timerValue));
    });
```

[image]

```
Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext(t -> {
    timerLabel.setText(TimeUtils.getTime(this.timerValue));
    })
    .subscribe();
```